# Ctrl+Z and Ctrl+Y shortcut stops working on launching live server on VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I am a beginner and started to learn development today. I realised that the moment I launch Live server (The one by Ritwick Dey) on VS code, Undo and Redo shortcuts stop working system wide. Other shortcuts like Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X etc all work fine both in VS code and Other applications, but the Ctrl+X and Ctrl+Y wouldn't work at all. However, on closing the VS code editor, the shortcut starts to work again. If I use VS code without live server then also no problem arises. How to fix it?

I have tried other live server extension but no help, I have tried to change keybinding and there I realised that after pressing Ctrl it doesn't read Z or Y at all.

Comment: did you double-check `settings.json` ? give me the contents of your `settings.json`

Comment: That's too long (7000+ lines of code) and exceeds characters limit

Comment: I'm positive the settings you're talking about is the `defaultsettings.json` (do not edit it)
user settings are usually around ~25.
ps: you don't have to paste it here. use pastebin

Comment: {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
}

Comment: I am sorry, I am figuring out how to use pastebin...meanwhile if possible have a look at this

Comment: Changing the live server browser to ms-edge from Chrome solves the issue. I don't know how but that works fine for me.

Comment: you have to change or delete this line: "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome" (make sure to take backup)

Comment: @mohsentux debugging details need to go in the question post. see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.